# How to make Drupal treat the parameter passed in url as different pages?

Tags: 8, uri

I have used successfully implemented a HelloWorld Example module. I have modified module to query mysql database and output based on url parameters. For Example,  visiting the following relative paths

- `/hello/rakesh` will output Detailed Profile of Rakesh.
- `/hello/shawn` will output Detailed Profile of Shawn.

I used the parameter passed in url to show a detailed profile of the person. I want Drupal to treat them as different pages. What changes should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by _I want Drupal to treat them as different pages_?

Answer (score 0):

Make a menu item (hook_menu() in your example module) with hello/%user as path. In the path callback, you process the parameter so the right profile is shown.

Comment: Hi Raf, Do you have a link to example code ?

Comment: Oh, wait, this is for Drupal 8? Same principle, different way. There's no hook_menu in Drupal 8. Check https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/routing for more info.